# Use javascript libraries installed by npm

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm sorry, but I'm very lost. Actually I have this:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import 'ts-angular-jsonapi';
```

And dont return any errors. But, when I do this

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as jsonapi from 'ts-angular-jsonapi';
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(14,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ts-angular-jsonapi'.
```

What changes need I do on `ts-angular-jsonapi` library for fix this errors.

More info: I need do this becouse I need make something like this:

```
class myresource extend jsonapi.resource {

}
```

Comment: Change `/src/index.ts` to not rely on the existence of `ts-angular-jsonapi` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment :(

Comment: Well, it seems that `./src/index.ts` expects the `ts-angular-jsonapi` variable to exist. So if you change `import 'ts-angular-jsonapi';` to `import * as jsonapi from 'ts-angular-jsonapi';`, it won't work anymore. Maybe you just have to change `ts-angular-jsonapi` to `jsonapi` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When you write a .TS file, you can not import any .JS file. You need use require(). In the code:

```
// some_file.ts
import * as angular from 'angular';
var jsonapi = require('ts-angular-jsonapi');  // .js library
```

But if you are searching the best and correct solution for typescript node module, I build a [simple example on github](https://github.com/pablorsk/typescript-node-module-example). With this example, you can do something like this:

```
import * as animal_module from 'animal_module';

class Snake extends animal_module.Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
}

let sam = new Snake('Sammy the Python');
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect, enable the `compilerOptions.allowJs` setting in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try
`import angular from 'angular'; import jsonapi from 'ts-angular-jsonapi';`

Comment: `import angular from 'angular'` says `Module ''angular'' has no default export.